# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading user input

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Whenever I try to use anything higher than `eq[0]`, I end up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] eq=in.next().split(" ");

        double a=Double.parseDouble(eq[0]);
        double b=Double.parseDouble(eq[-1]);

        if(eq[1]=="+"){
            System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a+b));
        }else if(eq[1]=="-"){
            System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a-b));
        }else if(eq[1]=="/"){
            System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a/b));
        }else if(eq[1]=="*"){
            System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a*b));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `eq[-1]`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @Tunaki @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ I tried `eq[2]` and got the same error

Comment: Problem with `String[] eq=in.nextLine().split(" ");`

Comment: @Tunaki `12 * 12` is what I've been testing with

Comment: don't compare string with `==` instead you must use `equals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> eq[-1] -1 index is problem
>
> eq[1]=="+" // logical error use equals() method to compare String.

```
           Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] eq=in.nextLine().split(" "); // use nextLine() instead of next().
        
            double a=Double.parseDouble(eq[0]);// 1st operand
            double b=Double.parseDouble(eq[2]);// 3rd operand

            if(eq[1].equals("+")){ //operator // compare string with equals method not with (==).
                System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a+b));
            }else if(eq[1].equals("-")){
                System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a-b));
            }else if(eq[1].equals("/")){
                System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a/b));
            }else if(eq[1].equals("*")){
                System.out.println(">>"+String.valueOf(a*b));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, eq[-1] the index should not be valid. I think it is only valid for Python.
Secondly, when you want to compare 2 strings, you should not use ==. 
.equals function will help.